# How do you add the onClick handle on each object?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm sorry if my english is bad and I'm still learning the reactjs.

I wanted to make an app where I have a data of objects on each students. I tried using the `useState` to create my `onClick` handle to show the students approval on each month, but it applies to all my list of objects(students)? How do you make it on just each of them? Also after I clicked on it, I cannot disable the `active` class.

To explain it easier, I kind of wanted to make it like an FAQ type where I click on one of the questions and then the answer appears under it.

The `active` class is where I'm going to use it to show/hide the approval in the CSS.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {kkmsItems} from './items/kkmsItems'

const Kkms = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(true)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setState({ clicked: !false})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="kkms-items">
                {kkmsItems.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <h3 onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</h3>
                            <div className={state.clicked ? 'approval active' : 'approval'}>
                                <p>January: {item.january}</p>
                                <p>February: {item.february}</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Kkms
```

And this is the list of my objects:

```
export const kkmsItems = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        january: 'Approved',
        february: 'Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        january: 'Not Approved',
        february: 'Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Greg',
        january: 'Approved',
        february: 'Not Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Ash',
        january: 'Not Approved',
        february: 'Not Approved',
    }
]
```

Thank you so much, appreciate the help.

Comment: If my answer is correct, plz check it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a state array and you have to pass to the function handleClick index of clicked item:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {kkmsItems} from './items/kkmsItems'

const Kkms = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState( Array(kkmsItems.length).fill(true))

    const handleClick = (index) => {
        const stateUpdated = state.map((s ,i) => {
                 if(i == index) return !s
                 else return s
        })
        setState(stateUpdated)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="kkms-items">
                {kkmsItems.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <h3 onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>{item.name}</h3>
                            <div className={state.clicked ? 'approval active' : 'approval'}>
                                <p>January: {item.january}</p>
                                <p>February: {item.february}</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Kkms
```

Comment: Sry for the late reply, I tried this but still wont work. The items are now not clickable, it just shows there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you wanted to have each list item control its hide/show behavior independently of each other, meaning two of list items can be open simultaneously.

If that's the case, the most natural and simple way would be to extract a new component for list items and let it handle its own state. It would be much simpler than to maintain all the children's state in the parent.

```js
// Extracted component that handles its own state
const Item = ({ item }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setActive((active) => !active);
  };
  return (
    <li>
      <h3 onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</h3>
      <div className={active ? "approval active" : "approval"}>
        <p>January: {item.january}</p>
        <p>February: {item.february}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

const kkmsItems = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        january: 'Approved',
        february: 'Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        january: 'Not Approved',
        february: 'Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Greg',
        january: 'Approved',
        february: 'Not Approved',
    },
    {
        name: 'Ash',
        january: 'Not Approved',
        february: 'Not Approved',
    }
]

const Kkms = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="kkms-items">
        {kkmsItems.map((item, index) => {
          return <Item item={item} key={index} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Kkms />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.approval {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```